# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SQL Insert syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, csv

I am receiving a syntax error when trying to insert values from a csv to a database using java. Here is my code

```
   try{
  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename1));
  String line;

  while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
  String[]value=line.split(",");//Seperator


  System.out.println(value[0]);
  System.out.println(value[1]);
  System.out.println(value[2]);



 if (programused == "Example"){





 String sql="insert into websitehistory (Date, URL, VisitCount) "
      + "values (?,?,?)";

 pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
 pst.setString(1, value[0]);
 pst.setString(2, value[1]);
 pst.setString(3, value[2]);  

  pst.executeUpdate(sql);

  Update_exampleTable();

 }
```

Here is mysql query of inserting the separated values into the database. Value is an array that contains the in putted csv file, "filename1"

This is my table structure:

```
Field          Type     Null    Key     Default      Extra
Date           text     No              NULL
URL            text     No              NULL
VisitCount     text     No              NULL
```

And the type of data that is inside the csv file that I would like to insert:

```
31/01/2014  15:26:00,  https://www.youtube.com/,  13
31/01/2014  15:25:00,  https://www.youtube.com/,  17
30/01/2014  12:15:00,  https://www.facebook.com/, 20
```

This then throws a MySQL syntax error:

```
Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?)' at line 1.
```

If I replace the `?` with `value[0] value[1]` and so on, some of the data is inserted but retrieves gives a different SQL syntax error within the data but when using place holders none of the data is inserted into the table. Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call:

```
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Instead of:

```
pst.executeUpdate(sql);
```